# Is it possible to write an update query inside JdbcBatchItemWriter() method in SpringBatch

Tags: spring, spring-batch, jdbctemplate, sql-update

I have my ItemWriter code snippet as below

```
private static final String SYNC_UL_LEADS_UPDATE = "UPDATE SYNC_UL_LEADS  SET SFDC_ID = :SFDC_ID WHERE Email = :Email";

@Bean
public ItemWriter<SyncULLeads> syncUlLeadsUpdateWriter() {

final DataSource datasource = dataSource;

JdbcBatchItemWriter<SyncULLeads> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<SyncULLeads>().beanMapped()
                .dataSource(datasource).sql(SYNC_UL_LEADS_UPDATE)
                .assertUpdates(true).build();


return writer;
    }
```

Comment: well, what exactly is the problem? yup, in general this should work

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to write an update query inside JdbcBatchItemWriter() method in SpringBatch

Yes, that is possible, you can find an example here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/8762e3411557aaf887867f8d8594b01127538cb1/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/iosample/jdbcCursor.xml#L21

Edit: Explain how fields will be mapped to variables in SQL statement

Since you are using `.beanMapped()`, variables in the SQL statement will be mapped from the item `SyncULLeads` using Java Bean conventions (aka getters). This is explained in the javadoc of [JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder#beanMapped](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/builder/JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder.html#beanMapped--) and [BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider.html).

Comment: My Write is like this. private static final String SYNC_UL_LEADS_UPDATE = "UPDATE SYNC_UL_LEADS  SET SFDC_ID = :SFDC_ID WHERE Email = :Email";
 /* Update SFDC_ID from Lead and Contact Table */

 @Bean
 public ItemWriter<SyncULLeads> syncUlLeadsUpdateWriter() {
  System.out.println("***Inside syncUlLeadsUpdateWriter() method **");
  
  final DataSource datasource = dataSource;

  JdbcBatchItemWriter<SyncULLeads> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<SyncULLeads>().beanMapped()
    .dataSource(datasource).sql(SYNC_UL_LEADS_UPDATE).assertUpdates(true).build();

  return writer;
 }

Comment: Please don't add code in comments, it is not readable. Edit the question instead. And that's the same code as in the question. You can use an insert or update statement with the  `JdbcBatchItemWriter` as shown.

Comment: I have added in Question . but my question is how it will take arguments from Processor.For statement UPDATE CUSTOMER set credit = :credit where id = :id how :id value and :credit value will be picked from processor.

Comment: added explanation in answer. The processor will pass items of type  `SyncULLeads` to the writer. Since the writer is bean mapped, it will call getters to get values from the item and bind them in the SQL statement.